# How can I set the property spring.cloud.config.server.git.password using docker secret

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets, spring-cloud-config-server

I want to dockerize my spring cloud config server application. I am creating a docker secret `git-repo-pass` to store the github account password. I am setting the environment `SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD` with the default path for docker secrets that is `/run/secrets/git-repo-pass`. But, when I run the compose and inspect the container, I see that the environment is literally set to the path and not the contents of that path.

Sharing my docker-compose.yml file below,

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    config-standalone:
        container_name: config-standalone
        image: ss-config:1.0
        ports:
            - "8888:8888"
        secrets:
            - git-repo-pass
        environment:
            - SPRING-CLOUD-CONFIG-SERVER-GIT-PASSWORD=/run/secrets/git-repo-pass

secrets:
    git-repo-pass:
        external: true
```

Exception thrown:
`Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment] with root cause`

Please let me know if there is a way to load the application properties using docker secrets.
Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, secrets are just files, stored securely and mounted when container starts. It won't become an environment variable on its own, so you have to make that happen.

The **fastest** way for you to make things running is to modify the startup command to something like `export SPRING-CLOUD-CONFIG-SERVER-GIT-PASSWORD=$(cat /run/secrets/git-repo-pass) && <actual_command>`, which will read the file into an environment variable and then do whatever it suppose to do. You can make it right in the compose file with `command` option under service name.

The **right** way to solve this, is to make a second variable and change the application to read the file, located at the path stored in the variable. This is something like a common practice for Docker image maintainers to provide a second variable for secrets with `FILE` at the end, like `SPRING-CLOUD-CONFIG-SERVER-GIT-PASSWORD-FILE`.